# MySQL diff two similar tables, case when not in type 0, else type 1

Tags: mysql, sql, diff, difference

Supposed I have two tables as below, `table_a` and `table_b` are almost with the same data structure:

```
table_a
----------------------------
id    name  code     date_a
1    Alice  code_a   2021-01-09 05:23:00
2    Edward code_b   2021-01-14 05:23:00
3    Lann   code_b   2021-01-23 05:23:00
4    Anna   code_c   2021-01-25 05:23:00
....
....
29999 Ben   code_acbd  2021-03-31 05:23:00


table_b
----------------------------
id    name  code     date_b
1    Alice  code_a   2021-01-09 05:23:00
2    Edward code_b   2021-01-14 05:23:00
3    Lann   code_b   2021-01-23 05:23:00
4    Anna   code_c   2021-01-25 05:23:00
....
....
26582 Wesly   code_hsdf  2021-03-14 05:23:00
```

I can use the below SQL to query 3417 rows of `table_a` not in `table_b`, but how to type 0 when not in the list, else type 1?

```
select id from table_a
where date_a between '2021-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-03-31 23:59:59' and id NOT in 
(select * from(select a.id from table_a a left join table_b b
 on a.id = b.id 
where b.date_b between '2021-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-03-31 23:59:59' )t1);
```

My expected output is to add a new column `is_in_table_b` in `table_a`, `case when not in` type 0,else type 1

```
table_a
----------------------------
id    name  code     date_a                is_in_table_b
1    Alice  code_a   2021-01-09 05:23:00     1
2    Edward code_b   2021-01-14 05:23:00     1
3    Kelly   code_b   2021-01-23 05:23:00    0
4    Anna   code_c   2021-01-25 05:23:00     1
....
....
29999 Ben   code_acbd  2021-03-31 05:23:00   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the logic to the `select` clause:

```
select a.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from table_b b
                where b.id = a.id
               )
       ) as is_in_table_b
from table_a a;
```

Your query has additional filtering that the question does not describe.  You can add it to this query where appropriate.